# Is it possible to delete a file that is opened by a process under windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

For testing and simulation purposes I would like to delete a file that is currently open by my process.

The [CreateFile docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) state that it is possible to open a file in a mode (`FILE_SHARE_DELETE`) that allows the file the open handle is pointing to to be deleted by another operation. (And I already tried and confirmed this via CreateFile(FILE_SHARE_DELETE) + DeleteFile.)

What I would like to know now however is, whether it is possible at all that a file that is opened by anyone without above mentioned flag to be deleted somehow?

As far as I understand the [DeleteFile docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) it would not be possible with this functions, as

> The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that is open 
>   for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file.

Is there any other way to delete a file that is open, but does not have the FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag set?

Comment: Under some circumstances it can be renamed. This is useful in you want to upgrade/replace it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

The closest way to do something like this is to schedule delete on reboot using [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a target filename of `NULL`, and `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` in the `dwFlags` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a legitimate way to delete such a file. However, if you'd like to be bullet proof, bare in mind that there are tools that can close your handle from the outside, and then the file can be easily deleted ([Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is one such tool, but there are [others](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/deletelockedfiles.shtml)). If someone closes the handle of a file you've opened, you'll get an error trying to use that handle.

Comment: Also keep in mind that handle values can be recycled, so very strange things can happen (at least in theory) if you do this. Use it as a last resort when trouble-shooting something, not as part of production code.

Comment: @Leo Davidson - yes, I know... I tried to find Raymond Chen's post about that, but just couldn't locate it, so I left this note out. Have you by any chance read it? Would love to add the link, for future reference.

Comment: I was thinking of the same article but I can't find it either. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [DeleteFileTransacted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363916%28VS.85%29.aspx) , it allows to mark the file for deletion on close. But it doesn't fit you if you want to delete file immediately. If file has no `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag you need to close it first, but for this purpose you need to get file handle and then close it. But this requres using code injection techniques. I don't know how it can be done easier.

Comment: Same problem as before, I think. "The DeleteFileTransacted function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that is open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file."